# Can I use a recursive query to query a tree where the leaves reference another table?

Tags: sqlite, recursive-query

I have table A of rows with column "object_id", and 2 NULL columns A_id and B_id, each row of A (among rows with the same object_id) either references table A self or table B, ie columns A_id and B_id are mutually exclusive.

e.g.

```
Table A
object_id     A_id     B_id
...
1             NULL      5
1             3         NULL
1             NULL      7
3             NULL      2
3             NULL      3
...

Table B
object_id     data
...
2              15
3              16
5              17
7              18
...
```

My objective is to collect all unique data in all the B rows that belong to a given A object_id (like 1) and all its descendants.

Can this be done with a recursive CTE query?
If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean with "collect"? Show the desired output for this example.

Comment: Starting from A object_id 1, the result would be the list 17, 18, 15, 16 in no particular order.

Starting from A object_id 3, the result list would be 15, 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use a standard tree walk to collect all the A IDs. Then join those with the B table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE A_and_descendants(object_id) AS (
  VALUES (1)                              -- starts here

  UNION ALL

  SELECT A.A_id
  FROM A
  JOIN A_and_descendants USING (object_id)
)
SELECT B.data
FROM A
JOIN A_and_descendants USING (object_id)
JOIN B ON A.B_id = B.object_id;
```